# i want to plotshape previous bar

Tags: plot

im plotting at 5. consecutive bar. but i cant plot it at 4 bar ago(1. consecutive bar)
(actually my desire is drawing a block from 4 bar ago)  can you help me?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Consecutive Candles", overlay = true)

// Input: Number of consecutive candles to detect
consecutiveCandles = input.int(5, "Consecutive Candles", minval = 2)

// Calculate the color of the current candle based on close prices
currentCandleColor = close > open ? color.green : close < open ? color.red : color.gray

// Count consecutive same-color candles
var int consecutiveCount = 0
consecutiveCount := currentCandleColor == currentCandleColor[1] ? consecutiveCount + 1 : 1

// Check for reversal condition
reversalCondition = consecutiveCount >= consecutiveCandles

// Plot shape on the fifth consecutive candle
plotshape(reversalCondition and consecutiveCount == consecutiveCandles, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.new(#ffd900, 0), size = size.small)

// Alert for the reversal condition
alertcondition(reversalCondition, title = "Reversal Alert", message = "Consecutive same-color candles detected")
```

i tried barindex but i couldnt

Comment: What language is this ? Maybe you should add a tag to your post so that it is properly referenced, otherwise no one will ever find it and help you.